# Stuck with sql joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i am a newbie to sql. 
I have these tables:

**Table Individual:**

```
IndividualId  IndividualName  
Ind1          Mark
Ind2          Paul
ind3          Spencer
ind4          Mike
ind5          Hilary
```

**Table Agent:**

```
AgentId     IndId(foreignKey)
Agent1      ind1
Agent1      ind2
Agent2      ind1
Agent3      ind4
```

**Transaction Table** (Transaction can be made via agent or by individual himself):

```
TranId   IndId(foreignKey/Never Null)  AgentId(foreignKey)  TranAmount
Tran1    ind1                          Agent1               $100
Tran2    ind1                          NULL                 $500
tran3    ind3                          NULL                 $200
tran4    ind4                          Agent3               $50
tran5    ind4                          NULL                 $30
```

Result should be like: (If Transaction is associated with Agent, then display in same line else display on separate line)

```
IndividualId  IndividualName  AgentId    TranId    TranAmount
Ind1          Mark            Agent1     Tran1     $100
Ind1          Mark            Agent2     NULL      NULL
Ind1          Mark            NULL       Tran2     $500
Ind2          Paul            Agent1     NULL      NULL
Ind3          Spencer         NULL       Tran3     $200
ind4          Mike            Agent3     tran4     $50
ind4          Mike            NULL       tran5     $30
ind5          Hilary          NULL       NULL      NULL
```

As per some comments, i used the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IndividualId, IndividualName, TranId, Agent.AgentId, Amount 
FROM Individual 
LEFT JOIN Transactions 
ON   Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId 
LEFT JOIN Agent 
ON   Transactions.AgentId = Agent.AgentId
```

Which gave the below results which are not correct:

```
IndividualId    IndividualName  TranId  AgentId Amount   
ind1            Mark            Tran1   Agent1  100  
ind1            Mark            Tran2   null    500  
ind2            Paul            null    null    null  
ind3            Spencer         Tran3   null    200 
ind4            Mike            Tran4   Agent3  50 
ind4            Mike            Tran5   null    30  
ind5            Hilary          null    null    null
```

Comment: Please show your SQL query

Comment: The sql query i have isn't giving the right results. So i think it will just throw you guys off track. I have given the tables and what the resultset should be. Quite straightforward it is.

Comment: Take a look at how `left outer joins` work in these visual examples http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  It appears you want all records from Individual and those that match from agent AND all records from transaction that match an individual.  So start with individual `left join` to transaction and `left join` again to agent.  Individuals have transactions.  transactions are tied to agents.  Transactions can be done without agents.  So individual to transaction to agent. (left join each time)  Try that and post what you've done.

Comment: @xQbert That won't fetch row number 3,5 and 7. 
For example:
"Ind1              Mark        NULL       Tran2      $500" (Row3) 
won't be in the resultset because left joining Individual with Agent won't generate "ind1   Mark   NULL" which ideally should have been joined with the Transaction Table.

Comment: it should.  that's the point of a LEFT join to transaction first. based on individual ID  so the left join will return all records from individual and those that match in transaction.  Which will be rows 3,5,7.  left join again to agent based on agentId to agentID and that will give you the details for transaction amount.  try it show what you've done and we'll help from there.  Show the work.  Individual-->Transaction-->Agent

Comment: Suhail, don't worry, it will not throw us off (I'm sure at least one person will be able to follow), especially since you have provided your expected results. People want to see your queries  because the community wants to see the effort you put forward in solving the problem. It may help someone else avoid the same errors in the future.

Comment: @xQbert I used the below query:  "SELECT Distinct IndividualId, IndividualName, TranId,Agent.AgentId, Amount FROM Individual left join Transactions on Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId left join Agent on Transactions.AgentId = Agent.AgentId" Which gave the following resultset: IndividualId IndividualName TranId AgentId Amount ind1 Mark Tran1 Agent1 100 ind1 Mark Tran2 null 500 ind2 Paul null null null ind3 Spencer Tran3 null 200 ind4 Mike Tran4 Agent3 50 ind4 Mike Tran5 null 30 ind5 Hilary null null null  THIS IS NOT CORRECT

Comment: Suhail can you put that information in your question. When you put that kind of stuff in a comment it is useless because you can't read it.

Comment: @xQbert I tried this method, and it didn't present the results expected above. I don't know why but this one has me really stumped! I'm usually quite good with answering questions like this. It'd be interesting to see what the answer is.

Comment: @Sean Ok i did that. Any idea friends ?

Comment: Yep two separate queries with a union.  I just finished a fiddle.  I'm trying to figure out if it can be done with full outer joins instead though. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88fb3e/2/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Distinct IndividualId,  IndividualName, Agent.AgentId, TranId, Amount 
FROM Individual
Left join Agent ON Individual.IndividualId = Agent.IndId 
left join Transactions
  on Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId  and  Transactions.AgentId = Agent.AgentId
  union 
    SELECT Distinct IndividualId, Name,  TranId,NUll as AgentId, Amount 
FROM Individual
left join Transactions
  on Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId  and Transactions.AgentId is null
```

Comment: After fixing some minor typo's on order above... here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0855af/1/0) not quite right yet too many 3's

Comment: This worked for me. I did get some NULL valued rows but i can easily fo away with them. Besides those i needed as the actual query had some other tables to be joined in the same way and having these NULL's helped. In the last step i got rid of the Null's

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0855af/7

Distributed Query in 3 Parts  :

1) Transactions With Agent

2) Transactions Without Agent

3) Individual & Agent mapped With No Transaction

```
SELECT IndividualId,  IndividualName, Agent.AgentId, TranId, TranAmount 
FROM Individual
Inner join Agent 
  ON Individual.IndividualId = Agent.IndId 
Inner join Transactions
   on Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId  
  and Transactions.AgentId = Agent.AgentId
  union 
SELECT  IndividualId, IndividualName,  NUll as AgentId, TranId,tranAmount 
FROM Individual
left join Transactions
   on Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId  
  and Transactions.AgentId is null
  union 
SELECT  IndividualId, IndividualName,  NUll as AgentId, TranId,tranAmount 
FROM Individual
Inner join Agent 
  ON Individual.IndividualId = Agent.IndId 
left join Transactions
   on Individual.IndividualId = Transactions.IndId  
  and Transactions.AgentId = Agent.AgentId 
  where Transactions.tranID is null
```

Comment: Nope here's the fiddle showing results don't match [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0855af/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are joining the Transaction table to the agent table (when not every transaction had an agent), this means that your result set will not include transaction without agents. Since the transaction table itself already has an AgentId column you shouldn't need to union results to see the agent for the transaction. I'm making the assumption that the columns in expected result have the following associations (since the same columns are in more than 1 table, the assumption is important) : IndividualId and IndividualName are from the Individual table,, TranId and AgentId, and TranAmount are the results from the transaction table. **I am only including a join to the Agent table, in case you decide you want agent name returned**, otherwise you don't even need it.

```
SELECT I.IndividualId, I.IndividualName, T.AgentId, T.TranId, T.TranAmount
FROM Individual I
LEFT JOIN Agent A ON I = IndId = A.IndId
LEFT JOIN Transactions T ON I.IndID = T.IndID
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!